# Wireless networks never show up, after trying almost everything

Tags: 12.10, wireless, networking, broadcom

I got a new laptop and I installed Ubuntu 13.04, and then I noticed wifi isn't working. I installed Ubuntu 12.10 and now I'm still at 12.10 with no wifi. I have this wireless USB card (I'm connected  using it now). Whenever I plugged in things work normally and wireless networks show up.

Yes, of course I have Broadcom and I removed the existing sta installation, installed b43-firmware with the legacy one (just in case), I removed, reinstalled bcmwl-kernel-source, I did set managed=true in networkmanager.config, I did update before installing b43-firmware, I almost did every single thing in other threads. I'm giving up, I hope this works or else I'll need to switch back on Windows..! Please help me:(

Since I've noticed you keep asking for codes to check some things, I'm going to post the output of running: `sudo lshw -C network`

```
sudo lshw -C network

    CI (sysfs)  
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 04
       serial: d4:c9:ef:50:df:9c
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=e1000e latency=0 multicast=yes
       resources: irq:17 memory:d4400000-d441ffff memory:d443a000-d443afff ioport:5020(size=32)
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:25:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d4000000-d4003fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@3:4
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: e8:4e:06:14:40:06
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=3.5.0-17-generic firmware=0.29 ip=192.168.0.102 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Answer (score 0):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

If there are no errors, detach the USB and let us have your report.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Linux firmware. Connect by cable/Ethernet
than

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe b43
```

Reboot disconnect cable/Ethernet and  you wireless should work.